# libmount equivalent for FUSE filesystems

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, fuse

What is the libmount equivalent function to mount a FUSE file-system. I understand that FUSE is not a real file system and my strace of mount.fuse shows opening a /dev/fuse file and doing some complicated manipulations.

I tried seeing how the mount.fuse works by reading [it's source code](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/util/fusermount.c) but not only it is needlessly complicated by string manipulations in C, it is a GPL program.

My question is, am I missing the obvious API to mount fuse file systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel interface for mounting a FUSE filesystem is described in "linux/Documentation/filesystems/fuse.txt" (for example, see [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/filesystems/fuse.txt)).

In a nutshell, you call `mount(2)` as you would to mount any filesystem.  However, the key difference is that you must provide a mount option `fd=n` where `n` is a file descriptor you've obtained by opening `/dev/fuse` and which will be used by the userspace process implementing the filesystem to respond to kernel requests.

In particular, this means that the mount is actually performed **by the user space program that implements the filesystem.**  Specifically, most FUSE filesystems use `libfuse` and call the function `fuse_main` or `fuse_session_mount` to perform the mount (which eventually call the internal function `fuse_mount_sys` in `mount.c` that contains the actual `mount(2)` system call).

So, if you want to mount a FUSE filesystem programmatically, the correct way to do this is to fork and exec the corresponding FUSE executable (e.g., sshfs) and have it handle the mount on your behalf.

Note that `/sbin/mount.fuse` doesn't actually mount anything itself.  It's just a wrapper to allow you to mount FUSE filesystems via entries in "/etc/fstab" via the `mount` command line utility or at boot time.  That's why you can't find any mounting code there.  It mounts FUSE filesystems the same way I described above, by running the FUSE executable for the filesystem in question to perform the actual mount.